# How can I remove last char in string in log file using Batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have log file `MyFile.txt` that contains the following lines of text:

> ```
> <RESPONSES Status="ERROR">
> <RESPONSE Status="Success">
> ```

Now I want to write a batch script that reports that an error has found when the string `status="ERROR"` was found.

This is what I tried so far:

```
@echo Off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET AA=Status="ERROR"
echo %AA%
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims= " %%a IN ( MyFile.txt) DO (
        ECHO %%c
                if "%AA%" == "%%b" (
                echo error found
            ) else (
            echo NO error
        )
    )
PAUSE
```

However, the trailing `>` symbols are causing an issue. Can Someone solve it?

Comment: Well, add `>` to the list of delimiters then. Anyway, you don't even need a script for that, you could simply use a [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) command line: `findstr /C:"Status=\"ERROR\"" "MyFile.txt" > nul && (echo error found) || (echo NO error)`…

Comment: *N. B.:* To detect errors I would not search for specific error strings, rather I would search for strings that to *not* match the success string: `findstr /V /C:"Status=\"Success\"" "MyFile.txt" > nul && (echo error found) || (echo NO error)`…